# Spelling libraries (like hunspell) in UWP Applications?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, hunspell, nhunspell

I am porting an application for writers to the UWP platorm. The only piece of the puzzle i have left is the NHunspell library. I use it extensively for spell checking and thesaurus features. I've customized the heck out of it, and created custom dictionaries for various things (i.e. a different dictionary for each writing project). This library is a beautiful thing.

However, I can't seem to include this DLL in my UWP application.

1) Is there a way to force the usage of this DLL? I really do like how the NHunSpell system is set up. It makes common sense and is very fast and easy to use.

2) If not, can anyone recommend a better solution for custom dictionaries, customized spell checking, etc?

**Update 3**

After considerable update and reading online, I found a link discussing the theory of spell checking. Here is one quick example (the one I used the most).

http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/how-to-write-a-spelling-corrector-in-csharp/

After reading this article, taking that base code, and stripping the English words from the Hunspell .dic files, I have created my own spell-checking library that works in UWP.

Once I get it solidified, I will post it as an answer below to donate to the SO community. :)

**Update 2**

I'm conceding the use of Hunspell. It doesn't look like it is possible at all... are there any other libraries/packages that anyone can suggest?

**UPDATE :**

I probably need to rephrase the statement that I can't include the DLL: I cannot include the DLL through NuGet. It complains that the DLL is not compatible with the UAP/UWP platform.

I am able to **MANUALLY** include the DLL in my project by linking to an existing DLL (not NuGet). However, that DLL does indeed prove to be incompatible with the UAP platform. A simple call to spellcheck a word works fine in WinForms, but immediately crashes with `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

The constructor of NHunspell does reach out to load the associated `.dic` and `.aff` files. However, I have mitigated this by loading the files into memory and then call the alternate constructor which takes a byte array instead of a file name for each of those files. It still crashes, but with a new `Method not found` error:

`String System.AppDomain.get_RelativeSearchPath()`

I am looking for any spell checking engine that will work within the UAP framework. I would prefer for it to be NHunspell simply for familiarity reasons. However, I'm not blind to the fact that this is becoming increasingly less-possible as an option.

People I work with have suggested that I use the built-in spellchecking options. However, I can't use the built-in Windows 10/TextBox spell checking features (that I know of), because I can't control custom dictionaries and I can't disable things like auto-capitalize and word-replacement (where it replaces the word for you if it thinks it is close enough to the right guess). Those things are chapter-suicide for writers! A writer can turn them off at the OS level, but they may want them on for other apps, just not this one.

Please let me know if there is a work-around for NHunspell. And if you don't know of a work-around, please let me know your best replacement custom spellcheck engine that works within the UAP framework.

As a side note, I also use NHunspell for its thesaurus capability. It works very well in my windows apps. I would also have to replace this functionality as well -- hopefully with the same engine as the spellcheck engine. However, if you know of a good thesaurus engine (but it doesn't spell check), that's good too!

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are you building from source?

Comment: I did not build the NHunspell from source. In previous releases (not UWP), I used NHunspell from NuGet packages. With my UWP app NuGet tells me that NHunspell is not compatible.

Comment: NuGet is right, you need to build the library from source code using the UWP SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I download the source code of NHunspell library and I tried to build a library with UWP support, however I found problems with the Marshalling (**Marshalling.cs**)
The package loads dlls that only working in x86 and x64 architecture, so in arm (mobiles, tablets) the app will not work.
The package loads dlls with system calls:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string fileName);
```

and I think that it needs to be rewrite for working in UWP, because UWP uses a sandboxing.

IMHO there are only two options:
1) Rewrite the Marshalling class with the restrictions of UWP.
2) Not use Hunspell in your program.

I don't have a large knowledge about dlls with UWP, but I believe that the rewrite could be very difficult.

Comment: I am very grateful for your attempt! Thank you for explaining. Great explanation. Do you know of any package OTHER than nhunspell for spelling and thesaurus? I've done a search online and found nothing useful. (alot of references to other packages like apsell, but none of those will work in UWP either)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't find other library that can replace nhunspell. However I think that you can develop a web with nhunspell and then you can create a web hosted UWP. Maybe this can resolve the  problem

Comment: No problem. See my latest update. I really appreciate your input, though.

Comment: Thanks, I hope that your library works well and can help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As promised, here is the class I built to do my spell checking.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Com.HanelDev.HSpell
{
    public class HSpellProcess
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public int MaxSuggestionResponses { get; set; }

        public HSpellProcess()
        {
            MaxSuggestionResponses = 10;
        }

        public void AddToDictionary(string w)
        {
            if (!_dictionary.ContainsKey(w.ToLower()))
            {
                _dictionary.Add(w.ToLower(), w);
            }
            else
            {
                // Upper case words are more specific (but may be the first word
                // in a sentence.) Lower case words are more generic.
                // If you put an upper-case word in the dictionary, then for
                // it to be "correct" it must match case. This is not true
                // for lower-case words.
                // We want to only replace existing words with their more
                // generic versions, not the other way around.
                if (_dictionary[w.ToLower()].CaseSensitive())
                {
                    _dictionary[w.ToLower()] = w;
                }
            }
        }

        public void LoadDictionary(byte[] dictionaryFile, bool resetDictionary = false)
        {
            if (resetDictionary)
            {
                _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dictionaryFile))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    string tmp = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    tmp = tmp.Replace("\r\n", "\r").Replace("\n", "\r");
                    string [] fileData = tmp.Split("\r".ToCharArray());

                    foreach (string line in fileData)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.StartsWith("#"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        string word = line;

                        // I added all of this for file imports (not array imports)
                        // to be able to handle words from Hunspell dictionaries.
                        // I don't get the hunspell derivatives, but at least I get
                        // the root word.
                        if (line.Contains("/"))
                        {
                            string[] arr = line.Split("/".ToCharArray());
                            word = arr[0];
                        }

                        AddToDictionary(word);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void LoadDictionary(Stream dictionaryFileStream, bool resetDictionary = false)
        {
            string s = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dictionaryFileStream))
            {
                s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            byte [] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

            LoadDictionary(bytes, resetDictionary);
        }

        public void LoadDictionary(List<string> words, bool resetDictionary = false)
        {
            if (resetDictionary)
            {
                _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }

            foreach (string line in words)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.StartsWith("#"))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                AddToDictionary(line);
            }
        }

        public string ExportDictionary()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string k in _dictionary.Keys)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(_dictionary[k]);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public HSpellCorrections Correct(string word)
        {
            HSpellCorrections ret = new HSpellCorrections();
            ret.Word = word;

            if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(word.ToLower()))
            {
                string testWord = word;
                string dictWord = _dictionary[word.ToLower()];
                if (!dictWord.CaseSensitive())
                {
                    testWord = testWord.ToLower();
                    dictWord = dictWord.ToLower();
                }

                if (testWord == dictWord)
                {
                    ret.SpelledCorrectly = true;
                    return ret;
                }
            }

            // At this point, we know the word is assumed to be spelled incorrectly. 
            // Go get word candidates.
            ret.SpelledCorrectly = false;

            Dictionary<string, HSpellWord> candidates = new Dictionary<string, HSpellWord>();

            List<string> edits = Edits(word);

            GetCandidates(candidates, edits);

            if (candidates.Count > 0)
            {
                return BuildCandidates(ret, candidates);
            }

            // If we didn't find any candidates by the main word, look for second-level candidates based on the original edits.
            foreach (string item in edits)
            {
                List<string> round2Edits = Edits(item);

                GetCandidates(candidates, round2Edits);
            }

            if (candidates.Count > 0)
            {
                return BuildCandidates(ret, candidates);
            }

            return ret;
        }

        private void GetCandidates(Dictionary<string, HSpellWord> candidates, List<string> edits)
        {
            foreach (string wordVariation in edits)
            {
                if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(wordVariation.ToLower()) &&
                    !candidates.ContainsKey(wordVariation.ToLower()))
                {
                    HSpellWord suggestion = new HSpellWord(_dictionary[wordVariation.ToLower()]);

                    suggestion.RelativeMatch = RelativeMatch.Compute(wordVariation, suggestion.Word);

                    candidates.Add(wordVariation.ToLower(), suggestion);
                }
            }
        }

        private HSpellCorrections BuildCandidates(HSpellCorrections ret, Dictionary<string, HSpellWord> candidates)
        {
            var suggestions = candidates.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value.RelativeMatch);

            int x = 0;

            ret.Suggestions.Clear();
            foreach (var suggest in suggestions)
            {
                x++;
                ret.Suggestions.Add(suggest.Value.Word);

                // only suggest the first X words.
                if (x >= MaxSuggestionResponses)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

        private List<string> Edits(string word)
        {
            var splits = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
            var transposes = new List<string>();
            var deletes = new List<string>();
            var replaces = new List<string>();
            var inserts = new List<string>();

            // Splits
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                var tuple = new Tuple<string, string>(word.Substring(0, i), word.Substring(i));
                splits.Add(tuple);
            }

            // Deletes
            for (int i = 0; i < splits.Count; i++)
            {
                string a = splits[i].Item1;
                string b = splits[i].Item2;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
                {
                    deletes.Add(a + b.Substring(1));
                }
            }

            // Transposes
            for (int i = 0; i < splits.Count; i++)
            {
                string a = splits[i].Item1;
                string b = splits[i].Item2;
                if (b.Length > 1)
                {
                    transposes.Add(a + b[1] + b[0] + b.Substring(2));
                }
            }

            // Replaces
            for (int i = 0; i < splits.Count; i++)
            {
                string a = splits[i].Item1;
                string b = splits[i].Item2;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
                {
                    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
                    {
                        replaces.Add(a + c + b.Substring(1));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Inserts
            for (int i = 0; i < splits.Count; i++)
            {
                string a = splits[i].Item1;
                string b = splits[i].Item2;
                for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
                {
                    inserts.Add(a + c + b);
                }
            }

            return deletes.Union(transposes).Union(replaces).Union(inserts).ToList();
        }

        public HSpellCorrections CorrectFrom(string txt, int idx)
        {
            if (idx >= txt.Length)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Find the next incorrect word.
            string substr = txt.Substring(idx);
            int idx2 = idx;

            List<string> str = substr.Split(StringExtensions.WordDelimiters).ToList();

            foreach (string word in str)
            {
                string tmpWord = word;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                {
                    idx2++;
                    continue;
                }

                // If we have possessive version of things, strip the 's off before testing
                // the word. THis will solve issues like "My [mother's] favorite ring."
                if (tmpWord.EndsWith("'s"))
                {
                    tmpWord = word.Substring(0, tmpWord.Length - 2);
                }

                // Skip things like ***, #HashTagsThatMakeNoSense and 1,2345.67
                if (!tmpWord.IsWord())
                {
                    idx2 += word.Length + 1;
                    continue;
                }

                HSpellCorrections cor = Correct(tmpWord);

                if (cor.SpelledCorrectly)
                {
                    idx2 += word.Length + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    cor.Index = idx2;
                    return cor;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the windows built-in spell checker directly so you can control it's behavior better. And then apply your results to the textbox control yourself.

Have a look at [ISpellChecker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It let's you [add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) your own custom dictionary and has a lot more options to control its behavior. And yes, it's available for UWP.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'd seen this before, but I have two major concerns with it. 1) Microsoft went out of their way to mark that interface as "Do Not Use" in their documentation. Not a big deal, but worries me and 2) More importantly, even if I did build this, I have found no specific way of telling my app to use *MY* spellcheck class instead of the built-in spellcheck class.

Comment: The docs say "do not implement", not "do not use". That's a big, big difference!

Comment: Not sure what you need your own spellcheck "class" for - with this you don't need one.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
and here's a sample:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/spell-checking-client-aea0148c